# Should I mark an answer as correct if it was posted after the question was solved?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is in reference to this question:

[cannot convert input text to int in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598009/cannot-convert-input-text-to-int-in-javascript)

RompePC managed to diagnose my problem in the comments at about the same time MaxZoom posted an answer. MaxZoom's answer didn't really address the actual problem I was having, and was quickly deleted (by MaxZoom). Then I commented that RompePC fixed my problem, and shortly after MaxZoom undeleted his answer and edited it to address the same problem RompePC pointed out.

It seems like, for the sake of Stack Overflow, I should mark MaxZoom's answer in case someone else has a similar issue, but it feels strange giving the credit to someone who submitted an answer a short while after I confirmed someone else solved the problem.

Should I mark MaxZoom's answer as correct?

Comment: If you want +2 rep, yes. Otherwise, you're not obliged to.

Comment: You can also wait and see if RompePC also provides an answer and accept his instead.

Comment: You can also leave a comment for RompePC that because he helped, if he posts his comment as an answer you will mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: You're free. And it also happens that some people accept an answer, then later on accept a different one because the new or updated answer was better than the previous one.

Comment: You have no obligation of accepting any answer.

Comment: This happens quite often due to some people answering in the comments section. However, the least that MaxZoom could have done is to properly credit RompePC.

Comment: Writing an answer takes much more effort than a comment. I frequently give an answer in the comments section when I don't have the time to format, attribute and provide a full code sample, or if the information sits at the other end of a link that I can't be bothered to repeat. I do this fully-aware that I might forgo rep to another user who decides to make a full answer out of my comment. That's what happens when you give away the answer in the comments. If I didn't want this to happen, then I'd be hoarding the knowledge solely for the gaining of rep. That sounds somewhat petty to me.

Comment: @spender I wish more people would take your stance on the rep greed found on this site. Not complaining about SO, but glad to know I am not the only one.

Comment: @spender interesting, when I write an answer I rarely format, I don't need to attribute, and most of the time I do not offer a example.

Comment: @spender - good point.  If the answer shows a lot more work than the comment, then it could deserve at least an upvote for being useful.  Also, I do the same thing in comments -- a quick possible answer when I don't want to take the time to write up something more detailed.

Comment: At the very least you can get someone going in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I left a comment for RompePC to put their comment as an answer. The "correct" way, which will properly attribute the resolution of your problem, would be to mark RompePC's answer as the Accepted Answer. However, as others stated in the comments to this question, you're under no obligation to accept *any* answer, though that does help future visitors to your question.

Given the edit history of MaxZoom, and your account of what happened, I would be a little reticent of giving Max the Accepted Answer. It doesn't seem like they actually found the answer on their own. However, if RompePC doesn't post their own answer before you stop caring, I would mark Max's as your Accepted to help those coming to your question later.

Comment: Another option, if Rompe doesn't want to post an answer, is for OP to post an answer instead (I, for one, don't mind OP's making answers out of my comments when I don't feel like it), and accept that (if they *really* don't want to give Max credit).