# Can this audit be removed from the system?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Note upfront: This question is based off of a question I recently asked (poorly). I have drastically narrowed the scope, have further refinements, and removed the old question.

I recently failed this Late Answer audit and believe it needs to be removed from the system: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16469504

[image]

When looking at the link, keep in mind that the comments were stripped out of it during review. I looked at this one for awhile before I clicked "Looks Ok." Is this a high quality, well written answer? Absolutely not. However, it is not spam, is relevant to the question asked, and curtly answers the question. In fact, after the comments were revealed it showed that this same information was left by the OP as a comment in his own question saying that it solved his problem; therefore it was in fact a correct answer. Other Meta posts have discussed [the ethics of turning other peoples' comments into answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350854/should-i-mark-an-answer-as-correct-if-it-was-posted-after-the-question-was-solve), but that's not what this post is about.

The only upside to this was I found another answer on the same question by the same user that did the exact same thing (stole an answer from other peoples' comments) and was left intact. I flagged that answer as well and it is now removed.

This audit was not 100% unambiguous. Can a moderator please remove it from the system so it doesn't get anyone else?

Comment: Surely that's kind of a terrible answer even without the comments, eh? I mean, the OP's own comment had more information than this answer, and even that was pretty terse; even if you wouldn't necessarily downvote this, maybe you could've left a comment asking the author to elaborate a bit on what solving the missing file might involve?

Comment: It's not though. It actually turned out to be THE answer. It is brusque, but being that blunt and direct seems to be accepted by the community. My point is that it is a direct answer to the question and cannot be distinguished as a poor answer without the context of the original post's comments. It doesn't make it a good answer, but it does make it a poor audit.

Comment: It's also deleted. As is the previous answer that said the same thing (but also noted where the file should be placed). Wouldn't it have been great if someone had asked one of those authors to flesh out their answer?

Comment: @Shog9 It's deleted because [of careless reviewers who didn't even read it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650500/error-e0505-e0505-app-definition/44193855#comment75448818_44193855). It should never have been deleted in the first place; perhaps downvoted (though it *does* answer the question).

Comment: Please [see my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351095/can-this-audit-be-removed-from-the-system/351096#351096), @Rob

Comment: Not everything is an exact duplicate, @gnat. You seem to be implying that no one on this site can ever ask a question again about potentially bad audits because someone has already asked one before. This audit is not the same as the audit in that question, therefore they can't be exact duplicates. Also, there are a lot of comments on that other question that imply it too is a terrible question to use for an audit. There is still no resolution.

Comment: did you check [the answer in duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601)?

Comment: It's deleted because of reviewers who did the right thing, @Rob: they removed a distracting scrap of a post that added nothing to the site, and was incoherently repeating information that was [already present in an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34411466/603977).

Comment: No one is debating if that answer was a precious diamond or not. But did it make a good audit question? It seems like we had to go through a lot of cyber sleuthing to figure all this out which seems to fall outside the realm of a good audit.

Comment: I don't really know why an audit should not require as much investigation as a real review. If you looked at the context, which is honestly just about always a good idea while reviewing, you would have seen the much earlier, much clearer answer. I think this was a pretty good audit; it demonstrated something to watch out for, and you've learned more about reviewing late answers.

Comment: @SandPiper: in future, do **not** just delete your question and re-post it.

Comment: The question I deleted was far too broad. It covered this and about two other topics. It had already fallen off of the radar, and I edited this content a lot. It is essentially a different question on the same topic.

Comment: If the standard is that on every review you click through to the original post and look at every aspect of the question, answers, and comments, then why is most of that information stripped out when looking at Late Answers? Why make someone go to that much trouble when it could all just as easily be presented to the user? The logic does not follow there. That standard of review seems to be above and beyond what the inventors of the review process had in mind. Is it not?

Comment: "why is most of that information stripped out when [reviewing...]?" It's a mystery. Even worse is the audits [that require literally inaccessible information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348617/spam-or-not-thats-the-question/348618#comment469772_348618).

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question... A moderator can simply undelete the answer to render it unsuitable for use as an audit.

Actually, the author of the answer themselves can do this - it was deleted by low-rep users via review, which performs a sort of light-weight deletion; if the author was to return and vote to undelete it, it would instantly be undeleted. A moderator flag would be raised though, so unless they also edited the answer it might just end up deleted again.

And therein lies the problem: in the two years this question has been on the site, multiple people (including the asker themselves) have tossed out terse suggestions like this, [but only one person has actually tried to explain *why* this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650500/error-e0505-e0505-app-definition/34411466#34411466): a property in a config file that points to the wrong location.

You could argue that these other answers were unfairly deleted, and I'd be sympathetic to that argument... However, I'm not at all familiar with Oozie Coordinator; if it's a badly designed system, perhaps there is no one root cause for these errors and the only sane way to answer this question in a generally-useful way is a pile of terse answers, each outlining some bit of voodoo that works in one case and not in others... OTOH, if the answer I linked to above does indeed identify the root cause here then these other answers are just confusing misinformation.

Regardless, you didn't encounter this audit in Low Quality review; you weren't asked to decide if the answer should be deleted, you were given the full range of options available on the post and told to use one of them and choose "No Action Needed" *only* if the post needed no action.

A terse answer to an old question which provides less information than existing answers *never* needs "no action". Depending on your knowledge of the topic, a down-vote, a flag, or a comment would've been appropriate here - *something* to guide the author toward writing a more informative answer than what had previously existed. That's why this answer was in review in the first place; if it hadn't been an audit, you would've failed its author by your review.

Comment: Honest question here: Does a terse answer to a new question "never need no action?", or is that only for new answers to old questions?

Comment: Second question: Is it expected to click through to the original question and look at everything in its original context for all entries in the Late Posts queue? If that is expected, why is that information not all immediately presented on the review screen? That seems to me to imply that it is not expected that you click through on every single issue.

Comment: There's an argument to be made ([here, if you're interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)) for having a quick answer that solves an immediate problem, and only bothering to flesh that out later @SandPiper. This argument falls apart pretty quickly as the question ages though, and certainly carries no weight once the asker has solved their own problem and long ago moved on; a late answer should at minimum provide *something* novel - new information, a better explanation, different phrasing... Something.

Comment: I only click through if there's something worth seeing, @SandPiper: if you glance at the right side of the page in review, you'll see an indication of how many other answers there are - for a low-quality late answer in particular, this is critical information. Folks trying to ride the coattails of existing answers by re-posting the same information is extremely common.

Comment: That is a good thing to watch out for. I know the audit will screw around with the date it was answered and the vote count on it, but will it display a false number of answers as well?

Comment: @SandPiper you may want to take a look at more detailed discussion of the issue mentioned by Shog in previous comment: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/839601)

Comment: "you weren't asked to decide if the answer should be deleted" remember that LQRQ also has a "Edit" action button. You are asked if you can fix this or delete it.

Comment: @Braiam You're asked if you can turn a post that merits deletion into one that's acceptable, or to delete it, or to indicate that it's already acceptable.  The LQP queue *is* there to determine if the post needs to be deleted, not to make minor improvements to posts.

Comment: @Servy again, you are twisting words: LPQ has 3 actions 1) Looks ok; 2) edit; 3) Recommend deletion/delete. LPQ is not a delete/not delete, there's no such dichotomy. Once you internalize that, the LPQ queue looks more colorful and powerful.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, the queue *has* an edit option, but the queue *is* asking you if the post merits deletion or not.  It *allows* you to edit the post if you feel you can turn a deletion-worthy post into one that's acceptable, but it's still fundamentally asking you if the post merits deletion.   Once you internalize that, the LPQ queue looks more colorful and powerful.

Comment: This was also not LQP, this was Late Answer.