# Why is this OK-looking Late Answer deemed unacceptable by the review queue?

Tags: support, review-audits, specific-answer, late-answers

I'm trying to do my best when reviewing **late answers** and other stuff and in some cases, I'm really puzzled as to why they are deemed "unacceptable"?

I mean, this question here is specifically about **ONE particular case**, one "late answer" and I really want to understand why exactly **this particular late answer** is not allowed to pass as "No Action Needed":

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18713854

Here's the screenshot of that particular "late answer": 
[image]

Note that the comments others had posted to that answer were deliberately hidden from me as a reviewer AND the question was **greyed out** to the point where it's almost invisible (suggesting that I don't need to pay any attention to the question).

And while that particular "late answer" may not be the best answer and it might not be technically correct, it does look fairly OK to **me as a reviewer who:**

- is NOT familiar with the subject matter
- did NOT have a chance to see the comments others had posted to that answer (because the comments are hidden when reviewing)
- did NOT read the question which this was posted as an answer to

So, under those conditions listed above (most important being me NOT being the subject matter expert on that topic), that answer looks OK because:

- it appears to provide a **succinct** but reasonably good answer and even has
- proper code formatting

While I do comment on code-only answers, that particular answer is NOT a code-only answer. It tells clearly what to do and provides 2 lines of text for each case.

Did the user HAVE to provide more information/explanation for that code?

I don't think so. It's 2 lines of code that seem to self-explain itself.

**Did the user have to write an article explaining 2 lines of code?** I hope not.

How could I (who is NO subject matter expert on that topic, who has NOT seen the comments posted to that answer and who has NOT read the question which this was an answer to), how should I possibly have acted other than clicking the "No Action Needed" button in this particular case?

Do we have to prevent users from posting **succinct** answers? Why??

### Please help me untangle this particular case!

Because I really want to improve and it annoys the hell out of me whenever I fail a test but **especially in this case**.

Under the circumstances listed above, this test answer does appear to be purely a "gotcha" test that has been deliberately designed to ensure I fail the test.

And if that's NOT the case (I really hope it's not), then I want to know EXACTLY... to the most excruciating detail, **what makes that answer an unambiguous fail?**

Because IF it's not an unambiguous fail, then it's an answer purely designed to annoy the reviewers. But I really hope that's not the case and that's why I want to ensure that I never fail such a test again.

### What exactly should I have done instead of clicking "No Action Needed" *in this particular case* and WHY exactly?

Comment: `"a reviewer who ...is NOT familiar with the subject matter..."` -- shouldn't you choose the **skip** option when reviewing these types of answers? This is precisely why this option exists, so that we don't make the mistake of moderating things that we are not familiar with.

Comment: Maybe it desn't work at all?   Should the code not be hiding 'sender' instead of 'this'?

Comment: _"did NOT read the question which this was posted as an answer to"_ Why not?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Really? But do you realize that this also means that I would **have to read the actual question first** to be able to tell whether or not that answer is meaningful... And since the question is greyed out, it does NOT suggest that I should read the question. Does it? How could ANYONE determine whether or not an answer is OK without first reading the question? Could you?

Comment: @JoshCaswell **Because the question is greyed out** and to me, that's a clear indication that the question itself does not matter and that I should not focus on the correctness of the answer but rather just check whether everything else looks OK. Do you see that differently? If yes, WHY?

Comment: _"greyed out"_ There's unfortunately lots of things about the review queues that are frustrating, make little sense, or are outright harmful. They're a bolted-on half-solution to a problem that the site owners fundamentally don't  want to solve.

Comment: So if i post a COMPLETELY valid python code as an answer on a PHP question, but because it's late it goes in the review queue... the fact my answer has NOTHING to do with the question is important. How do you expect to know that without checking the question? It just seemss silly. An answer should be contextual to the question asked...I cannot see how you think a review can be good without checking the question, greyed out UI or not (and doesn't the grey out gets less obvious as you mouse over anyway, hinting there is SOME importance to the question?

Comment: @Patrice That's a fair point. But WHY then is the question **GREYED OUT** to the point it's almost invisible?? Shouldn't the question be displayed prominently if I'm supposed to pay attention to that?? Do you ever try to click a button that's greyed out? What does it tell you if a button is greyed out??? It tells you: Unimportant! Don't click it! RIGHT?

Comment: Again, If you mouse hover doesn't the greying out goes away? i am honestly not sure I haven't done late answers in a while. But the simple fact you can't spot answers in the wrong language  (for example) without checking the Q should be a good enough indication the question should be checked. Regardless of the UI. We can make the argument the UI could be improved. I don't think it's an excuse to not check the question, imho.

Comment: @Patrice Well, it certainly is an "excuse" to never touch "late answers" even with a 10-foot pole! Because all you'll be doing there 99% of the time is clicking the "skip" button. So, why even bother? Correct?

Comment: As for the comments removed argument:  if your reviews can only be accurate if there is already a hint from another user as to what the action should be... how valuable is the review?  "Why bother?" You don't need to be a c# guru to see the Q has nothing to do with the A here. You don't have to skip quite as often as you seem to think, IG you check the Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer this question myself before it gets closed.

Thanks to the insight from the comments of Josh Caswell and after reading this here:

[How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

I now understand that "first posts" and "late answers" should be treated with a different mindset than the way I had treated them so far. Until now I thought that if an answer looks like a half-way decent effort (and isn't spammy in any way), I thought they should be given "the benefit of a doubt" and allowed to be posted.

But now I know that late answers and first posts are very likely to be garbage and so the lesson is:

### If a first post or late answer smells even remotely fishy, then it probably is garbage and must be either flagged OR skipped *without trying to decipher a "potential good intent" of the poster* and without trying to give them the "benefit of a doubt"!

On the contrary, the filter for first posts and late answers must be harsher than for normal posts and answers. This is what I'm taking away from it.

Oh, and this answer here:

[How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

That should be a required reading for anyone before reviewing late answers or first posts.

**How the hell am I supposed to know those things if that information is not provided before I start reviewing late answers and first posts?**

With the information that I have now, I would have skipped that particular "late answer" from the test because even though the answer looked somewhat OK, I had mixed feelings about it and decided to give the "benefit of a doubt" whereas this should have worked in the other direction:

### If in doubt, either flag or skip!

Answer (score 14):

> did NOT read the question which this was posted as an answer to

I don't know why you're presenting this an an exculpatory fact, because it's actually the root of the problem. If you had looked at the question, you would have seen that it's about an application trying to show something on a second screen. The something continues to appear on the first screen instead.

Leaving aside the code in the answer (I'm not familiar with C# any more than you are), it tells you how to hide something or how to make the application exit.

Does that sound like a resolution to something being drawn on the wrong screen?

> How could ANYONE determine whether or not an answer is OK without first reading the question?

Absolutely right, you can't. So do that next time. Or, if you don't want to, or still can't really figure out what's going on, hit "Skip". "No action needed" means you have made a confident judgement that the post is good. It doesn't sound like that was the case here, so that's why it was the wrong choice.

You might be interested in the review guidance FAQ: [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180031#180031) There's also [a section there specific to Late Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/159251).

Comment: WHY is the question **greyed out** to the point where it's almost invisible IF I am supposed to read the question before judging the answer?

Comment: Because the review queues are stupid and nobody's working on their UX.

Comment: So, you are saying that: 
Even though the questions are **greyed out to the point where they are almost invisible** (suggesting they are unimportant) I actually DO have to read AND understand every question before judging a "late answer" AND that I also have to understand the answer itself AND judge whether or not that answer is correct before I can click "No action needed". **Is that what you are saying?**

Comment: That's what I'm saying. (Sometimes you can tell an answer's crap without looking at the question, though.)

Comment: I'm not discussing some hypothetical "sometimes" cases here! My question is about *ONE very specific "late answer"*. No theories, please!

Comment: Well, then just ignore everything in parentheses.

Comment: It's hard for me to believe this would be true because that would mean that 99.9% of all users wouldn't be able to review 99.9% of all "late answers" at all. Have you thought about the consequences of that?? If someone/anyone would have to click "skip" on 99% of all review answers, then almost all reviewers would immediately STOP doing their job! Would that be a desirable consequence?

Comment: [_"**General guidelines** If you're unsure how to review a post \(perhaps it's outside your areas of expertise\), skip it. Someone who understands it better will review it later."_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/159251) Further: [_"It's important to check if the answer is really relevant to the question. If you don't know the topic well enough to assess this, avoid actions beyond simple editing for format."_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/159251) Also note the presence of tag filters in Late Answers (one of the few good affordances of (some of) the review queues).

Comment: Just one sentence below of what you are linking to it says: **"Unless there is an existing comment that covers the situation, do add one"**. But "late answers" specifically do NOT display ANY comments to the reviewer! The comments are deliberately hidden from the reviewer! So, the bottom-line of this entire story seems to be: Do not bother ever looking at the "late answers" because you'll have to first read AND fully understand the corresponding question AND must then be able to understand whether or not the posted answer makes sense for that question. Right?

Comment: Under those conditions, would any sane person ever want to review "late answers"?

Comment: You have neatly expressed one of the core problems with the review queues in general.

Comment: Yes, had I seen the comments others posted to that "late answer", I would have NEVER approved that answer. But since those comments were deliberately hidden from me as a reviewer, **it DOES indeed look like that this particular "late answer" test was deliberately designed to ensure I fail the test!** One clear message I get from that is: **Stay the hell away from reviewing late answers if you want to keep your sanity!**

Comment: I'm afraid that [you are not the first to encounter this kind of thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351095/can-this-audit-be-removed-from-the-system#comment484795_3510950), nor will you be the last.